# Decoding javascript array of objects in php

Tags: php, json, curl

Needed help decoding the following curl response.

```
[{id:1, type:7, total: 246}, {id:1, type:7, total: 246}]
```

It is a complete string, not an array. Is there any possible way to decode and loop through every id.

Comment: Actually this response is an array of javascript objects. Not every word is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: this is called **JSON** data. You'll have no problem handling this in php. with tons of example here and on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

The example from documentation:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

This will give you:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is not in json format. It is in "javascript array of objects" format. If you see this [{id:1, type:7, total: 246}, {id:1, type:7, total: 246}], it is not in json format. I think it can be parsed using preg_match_all.

Note: The keys are not enclosed in quotes